# CodeIgniter Cookies are not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, codeigniter, session-cookies

I have a login page which is HTTPS and when user click on Log-In button if the username and password is correct I am redirecting to a logged In Home Page, which is a HTTP page. I came to know that only in IE8 user data is missing when I come to logged In Home Page. 
When I have both Log-In Page and Logged-In Home page in HTTPS then this problem not occurs also when the both pages are in HTTP also there is no issue. When we create the cookie in HTTPS and trying to access from HTTP this happens.

CodeIgniter Version : 2.1

**My Configuration as follows:**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = cisession;
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "test.com";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Please not this issue is not happens in Chrome / FireFox

It would be great if you guys can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library

https://github.com/staskus/codeigniter-2.--native-session.

It stores codeigniter session_id in php native session